# Escaping Parentheses in Regex

Tags: regex

I have a regex which has optional anchors at the end e.g.

```
(\.|,|\/)
```

I am trying to add ")" to this but if I escape it

```
(/.|,|\/|\))
```

it isn't found and if don't escape it is treated as part of the expression and fails since there is no open parens.  How can I escape it so it is treated as a character and found?

Comment: Why do you change from `\.` to `/.`? And can you add sample input/outputs?

Comment: Your question is unclear (at least to me). I don't think you're using the term [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) correctly, and I don't see what a missing open parenthesis has got to do with it. Could you post some actual code with inputs/expected outputs/observed outputs? If it's not clear from the code, please also state which regex engine you're using.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to match one of a set of character, it's best to use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). And within such a class, most escaping rules don't apply.

So to match a dot, comma, slash or closing parenthesis, you can use

```
[.,/)]
```

Comment: What about an opening or closing square bracket?

Comment: Depends on the regex engine. You can get away with `[]\[]` in most, but not in Javascript where `[]` is a legal (empty) character class. So `[\]\[]` is safer.

Answer (score 42):

`\)` is the correct way for escaping a paranthesis. Make sure you are properly escaping the `\`(`\\`) in the string literal.

Comment: If I understand your meaning correctly, I think "Make sure you are properly the slash. The correct way to do this is with the string `\\`" is clearer.

Answer (score 15):

**Alternative Solution**

Instead of a set, it can be easier to use the hex code. This code does not need *a C# escape*.

**Example**

The hex code for a `(` is `\x28` and its counterpart `)` is `\x29`.

To use in a pattern would look *exactly* like this to find anything between the parenthesis

`\x28[^\x29]+\x29` which escaped would be `\)[^)]+\)`

or searched in a different way:

`\x28.+?\x29`

Which all previous patterns would be able to match:

`(abc)`

---

I also use this in my regex patterns for the double quotes (`\x22`) and the single quote (`\x27`) which is the apostrophe.

It just makes working with the regex patterns easier while C# coding.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex should look like this:
`(\.|,|\/|\))`

Test it out with http://rubular.com/